# How to fetch Original Estimate fields from Jira using JirAgileR

Tags: r, jira, jira-rest-api

I am trying to fetch Original Estimate fields using timeoriginalestimate keyword using below code, but it is not returning the field. Although it is working fine for timespent.

```
library(JirAgileR, quietly = T)
library(knitr, quietly = T)
library(dplyr, quietly = T)

if (is.null(JIRABaseURL)) JIRABaseURL
if (is.null(username)) username
if (is.null(password)) password

fields1<-get_jira_issues(domain = JIRABaseURL,
username = username,
password = password,
jql_query = "project in('my_project')",
fields = c("summary","timespent", "timeoriginalestimate"),
maxResults = 150,
verbose = FALSE,
as.data.frame = TRUE)
```

How can I fetch original estimate, is there any specific keyword for the same?

Answer (score 0):

According to `supported_jql_fields()`, this field isn't yet supported.

```
 JirAgileR::supported_jql_fields()

 [1] "aggregateprogress"     "aggregatetimeestimate" "aggregatetimespent"   
 [4] "assignee"              "comment"               "components"           
 [7] "created"               "creator"               "description"          
[10] "duedate"               "environment"           "fixVersions"          
[13] "issuelinks"            "issuetype"             "labels"               
[16] "lastViewed"            "priority"              "progress"             
[19] "project"               "reporter"              "resolution"           
[22] "resolutiondate"        "status"                "summary"              
[25] "timeestimate"          "timespent"             "updated"              
[28] "versions"              "votes"                 "watches"              
[31] "workratio"             "parent"
```

However, it seems to be planned in the [Roadmap](https://github.com/matbmeijer/JirAgileR#roadmap)

Comment: Thank you!
Is it possible to add a filter for created date in above script?
For example created > 01-01-2021